# Does Scala have a "Scala Way" to use or set a variable?

Tags: scala, oop, lazy-loading, memoization

I want to use an instance variable if it is set.  And if it is not set, then perform the work to set it.

So this is what I want and it works:

```
class Devices(){
  private var _devices = List[Any]()

  def devices(): List[Any] = {
    // possibly other stuff
    _get_devices() // return processed list of devices
  }

  private[this] def _get_devices(): List[Any] = {
    if (_devices.isEmpty) {
      _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()
    }
    _devices
  }

  private[this] def _initialize_list_of_devices(): List[Any] = {
    List[String]("_initialized") // perform time-consuming processing
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic Scala Way of doing it.

I also cannot use `lazy val` because I need to modify the variable later on.

In Ruby, it would be something like lazy-loading, memoizing, or this:

```
def my_attribute
  @my_attribute ||= initialize_my_attribute
end
```

or

```
def my_attribute
  @my_attribute = (value || initialize_my_attribute)
end
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about what you are trying to do? Majority of the Scala developers will advice against using `var` and `Any`. The latter is there to really just have a complete type system and I guarantee you will give you a lot of headache down the road.  `var` is just not recommended as most devs subscribe to the immutable data idea. Whenever I found myself using `var`, there was always a way of doing it cleaner with `val` so maybe we can help with that, making the answer below usable for you

Comment: Scala doesn't have it out of box. I made a LazyVar https://github.com/texasbruce/scala-boilerplates/blob/master/LazyVar.scala you can take a look. If you don't need thread safety, you can also remove the synchronized block to increase performance

Comment: @texasbruce thanks for confirming there’s no prescribed way of doing what I want

Comment: @sinanspd thanks for the offer. I am sticking with regular OOP for now. I will give functional programming a try on the second iteration. Thanks again 

Comment: In your specific case, it's actually okay to use `lazy val` with `s.c.mutable` collection types btw.

Comment: There’s more to the class than what I posted. I just wanted to keep the question simple.

Comment: I understand that. I am saying, if your variable can be made into mutable object like collections, you can utilize lazy val just fine. Solutions depend on requirements

Comment: @texasbruce gotcha. Thanks 

Comment: @texasbruce I'm re-reading your previous comment and I think I understand it better now.  Do you have an example of how to use `scala.collection.mutable`'s `lazy val`?  This is the closest doc I could find and I am not understanding how to implement what you were referring to.  https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html

Comment: The only think I can think of is to do something like `lazy val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Any]`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Something like `lazy val devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()` where the function returns a mutable List

Comment: okay gotcha.  and `_initialize_list_of_devices()` will return a mutable `bufferedList` from `s.c.mutable`.  Okay thanks.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @sinanspd I've typed out the problem I am trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028729/how-to-do-this-more-functionally-and-in-line-with-the-scala-way
Hopefully, with more of the implementation detailed in that question, it is easier to understand the extent and requirements of what I'm trying to do.  Thanks again for your suggestion 

Comment: @texasbruce I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I tried `private lazy val _devices = ListBuffer[Device]()` and still get `reassignment to val` error.  I think I'm going to give up and assume it's not possible.  Thanks again for all of your help 

Comment: You use mutable collection the same way as in other language such as Java. You don't assign a new collection to it. Also you cant because its a val. Instead, you add/remove/reset elements directly on that instance, such as `devices.add(element)`, `devices += collection2`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lazy val` to postpone initialization of a variable until the time of first access:

```
class Devices(){
  private lazy val _devices: List[Any] = {
    List[String]("_initialized") // perform time-consuming processing
  }
}
```

It's safe to access `lazy val`s from multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I’ll need to modify that list later on in time so I can’t use `val`. I’ll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to type this out so I don't forget it in the future and in case it helps someone else later on.

@kolmar's answer and @SwiftMango's comments led me to this:

Devices.scala:

```
class Devices(){
  println("in constructor")
  lazy val _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices() // I swapped these two statements
  //val _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()    // to get at the results below

  def devices(): List[Any] = {
    println("in getter")
    _devices
  }

  private[this] def _initialize_list_of_devices(): List[Any] = {
    println("initializing=======")
    List[String]("_initialized") // perform time-consuming processing
  }
}
```

Main.scala:

```
  var devices_class = new Devices()
  val devices_list = devices_class.devices()
  devices_class.devices()
```

The output was this:
without `lazy` (i.e `val _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()`:

```
in constructor
initializing=======
in getter
in getter
```

with `lazy` (i.e `lazy val _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()`:

```
in constructor
in getter
initializing=======
in getter
```

What I learned and gained clarity on was this:

- `lazy` does not keep the initialization process from running more than once, i.e. it is not doing caching/memoizing
- `lazy` does postpone the initialization to when the variable is used, i.e. it is doing lazy-loading/evaluating
- `val` helps the programmer remember to not reassign to the variable (as opposed to `var`); and hence, (in a round about way) helps keep the initialization process to run just once, i.e. it is helping the programmer to remember to use the cached/memoized value of the variable.

I got confused between lazy and memoize/caching.

Thanks again for everyone's help